# Subscript notation to probability distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

What does a subscript (theta) to a probability distribution mean in $P_\theta(X)$? Does it mean a conditional distribution of X given $\theta$ like $P(X|\theta)$ or is it just a name of the fixed parametered (indexed) distribution?

Comment: It's usually the latter, although in a Bayesian context you can see it as the former.

Comment: Depends on the context in which you came across this. Both notations are common in classical inference where $\theta$ is some unknown quantity of interest and the distribution is parameterized by $\theta$. The $\theta$ could also be a random variable in Bayesian inference whence this is a conditional distribution.